# Laravel Socialite Login, localhost:8000 my laravel project is not running here... Guide please

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create Socialite Login using laravel. I have wamp server, and my project is running on http://localhost/SocialiteLogin/     <- on this url I am getting laravel logo/demo page.

Project is running well on my browser but when I type this address into (Create OAuth client ID->Authorized JavaScript origins) it gives me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW3uA.png):

> Invalid Origin: URIs must not contain a path or end with "/".

I have seen different videos related to this, their laraval project are running directly on localhost:8000 and they paste the same address into "Authorized JavaScript origins" but when I type this url(localhost:8000) I am getting error:

> This site cannot be reached.

Please tell me how can I set my project so that it run on localhost:8000 so that I can use it in Create OAuth client ID.

Comment: `/SocialiteLogin` is a path ... your site isn't running on port `8000` it is running on port `80` which is why you dont need a port defined in the URL to reach it, http is 80 ... the reason you are seeing videos or turorials or someone's random cat blog having `:8000` is probably because they are running `php artisan serve` to serve the site which uses port `8000` by default

Comment: i solve my problem using php artisan serve thanks....